# Force last '/' inside TRESTClient.BaseURL Method

Tags: rest, delphi

I'm trying to reach an api with this request url :

`https://myapi/api/v4/contract/id/recipients/`

In my code it looks like that :

```
var
  RESTClient : TRESTClient;
  ...

begin 
  RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create('');
  try
    RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://myapi/api/v4/contract/id/recipients/';
    ShowMessage(RestClient.BaseURL);
    ...
  finally
    RESTClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But instead of the URL I put inside my `RESTClient.BaseURL`it shows me:

> `https://myapi/api/v4/contract/id/recipients`

Is there a method that can force the last `/`? I tried the `IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter` method but that added a `\`instead. I also found a `IncludeTrailingSlash`method but my compiler did not recognise it.

Comment: Usually a trailing slash is not needed. What error do you get when it is missing?

Comment: I'm getting a `{"error":"not found"}` as the `Response.Content`. I get the same error in postman when i remove the last slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a `TRESTRequest` together with the `TRESTClient`, you should split the URL into the real `BaseURL` *https://myapi/api/v4* for the client and the `Resource` part *contract/id/recipients/* for the request. That way the combined URL for this request will contain the ending slash.

See: [TRESTRequest.Resource](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequest.Resource)